# Efficient way to combine multiple csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have over 100K CSV (total file size north of 150 GB) which I need to join. All have standard column names although the sequence of columns may not match and some csv have a few columns missing.

Now I just created a dataframe and kept concating the datframe from each csv in each iteration to have a standard dataframe containing all columns which I eventually intended to save as csv

I tried making a dataframe with 1000 sample csv and noticed as the dataframe size increased, the number of iteration dropped down from 10 to 1.5 per second which probably means that it would follow a similar trend if I got all-in with 100k csv thus taking days if not months to combine them.

Is there a better way of combining huge number of csv files?

Here is my code

```
df_t1 = pd.DataFrame()  
for i in tqdm(range(len(excelNames))):
    thisCSV = str(excelNames[i]).lower().strip()
    df = pd.read_csv(pathxl + "\\" + thisCSV, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False,low_memory=False)
    df["File Name"] = pd.Series([thisCSV for x in range(len(df.index))])
    if thisCSV.endswith('type1.csv'):
        df_t1 = pd.concat([df_t1,df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)  
df_t1.to_csv(outpath + "df_t1.csv", index = None, header=True, encoding='utf-8') 
print("df_t1.csv generated")
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic of `if thisCSV.endswith('type1.csv')`. Don't open all csv files if you want to keep only those ending by 'file1.csv'.

Comment: Actually, there are 4 types and each needs to be combined into 4 different data frames. I just showed the code with one type here but we will be using all the csv since it will fall in one of that 4 type. I just posted a simplified version of my actual code

Comment: 1) Since you have >150 GB of data won't there also be a memory issue with trying to place this all in one dataframe?  2)  pd.concat is inefficient to run in a for loop.  Faster to create a list of the dataframes and perform concat on the list.

Comment: @DarrylG 1) Exactly, that's probably why the number of iterations per second was dropping down as `i` was increasing and that's why I am  asking for an efficient process
2) Won't making a list of dataframes create the same memory issue with 100k csv files data?

Comment: @PrashantKumar--added code with possible improvement.  Can you provide feedback on it?

Answer (score 2):

Possible improvement

**Method 1: Using Pandas**

```
#df_t1 = pd.DataFrame()  
df_t1_lst = []
for i in tqdm(range(len(excelNames))):
    thisCSV = str(excelNames[i]).lower().strip()
 
    if thisCSV.endswith('type1.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(pathxl + "\\" + thisCSV, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False,low_memory=False)
        #df["File Name"] = pd.Series([thisCSV for x in range(len(df.index))]) --unnecessary to loop use next line instead
        df["File Name"] = thisCSV             # places thisCSV in every row
        #df_t1 = pd.concat([df_t1,df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)          # concat slow, append to list instead
        df_t1_lst.append(df)
        
df_t1 = pd.concat(df_t1_lst, ignore_index=True)       # Form dataframe from list (faster than pd.concat in loop)
df_t1.to_csv(outpath + "df_t1.csv", index = None, header=True, encoding='utf-8') 
print("df_t1.csv generated")
```

**Method 1a**

Using Pandas to continuously append to CSV output file

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def str_to_bytes(s):
    ' String to byte array '
    result = bytearray()
    result.extend(map(ord, s))
    return result


def good_file(file_path):
    """ Check if file exists and is not empty"""
    # Check if file exist and it is empty
    return os.path.exists(file_path) and os.stat(file_path).st_size > 0
    
SEPARATOR = ','   # Separator used by CSV file
write_header = True

pathxl = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
outpath = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
excelNames = ["xxx.csv", "xxxxx.csv"]

pathxl = r"C:\\Users\\darryl\\OneDrive\\Python"
outpath = pathxl + r"\\"
excelNames = ["test1_type1.csv", "test2_type1.csv"]

output_file = outpath + "df_t1.csv"
with open(output_file, "w") as ofile:
    pass   # create empty output file

for i in tqdm(range(len(excelNames))):
    thisCSV = str(excelNames[i]).lower().strip()

    input_file = pathxl + "\\" + thisCSV
    if thisCSV.endswith('type1.csv') and good_file(input_file):
        df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
        if df.shape[0] > 0:
            df['File Name'] = thisCSV                # Add filename
            df = df.sort_index(axis = 1)             # sort based upon colunn in ascending order

            # Append to output file
            df.to_csv(output_file, mode='a', 
                      index = False, 
                      header= write_header)

            write_header = False                     # Only write header once
            
        del df
```

**Method 2: Binary Files**

Reading/Writing binary and using memory-map should be faster.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import os
import mmap

def str_to_bytes(s):
    ' String to byte array '
    result = bytearray()
    result.extend(map(ord, s))
    return result

def good_file(file_path):
    """ Check if file exists and is not empty"""
    # Check if file exist and it is empty
    return os.path.exists(file_path) and os.stat(file_path).st_size > 0
    
SEPARATOR = ','   # Separator used by CSV file
header = None

pathxl = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
outpath = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
excelNames = ["xxx.csv", "xxxxx.csv"]

with open(outpath + "df_t1.csv", "wb") as ofile:
    for i in tqdm(range(len(excelNames))):
        thisCSV = str(excelNames[i]).lower().strip()

        input_file = pathxl + "\\" + thisCSV
        if thisCSV.endswith('type1.csv') and good_file(input_file):
            with open(input_file, "rb") as ifile:
                print('file ', thisCSV)
                # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
                with mmap.mmap(ifile.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mmap_obj:
                    text_iter = iter(mmap_obj.read().split(b'\n'))

                if header is None:
                    header = next(text_iter)
                    header = header.rstrip() +  str_to_bytes(SEPARATOR + "File Name\n")
                    ofile.write(header)  # write header
                else:
                    next(text_iter)        # ignore header row

                # write data to output file
                file_value =  str_to_bytes(SEPARATOR + f"{thisCSV}\n")
                for line in text_iter:
                    if line.strip():             # skip blank lines
                        ofile.write(line.rstrip() + file_value)
```

Comment: Yes, this is definitely faster than my method. I still see the number of iterations decreasing with time but it's not substantial on the sample files (~4k csv) as it was with my logic. I will soon run it on my 100k csv to see if it works or if I run out of memory. I will mark is as the answer if this does the trick

Comment: @PrashantKumar--thanks, but one concern is the pd.concat at the end which is not in the iteration loop.  I wonder how much time it takes to concat all the dataframes together at the end.

Comment: Took ~ 6 minutes for the whole run. 4 min for the loop and 2 min to concat and generate csv with this new method. With the old method it took 35 minutes for 4k+ csv lol

Comment: @PrashantKumar--added a second method based upon doing the simplest IO (i.e. avoiding data conversion by staying binary).  Just have to set `pathxl , outpath and excelNames`.  Could you check the time on this?

Comment: Okay so Method 1 crashed because of out of memory issue
Method 2 was faster but again it had its own problem like it would add an extra row at the end of the data frame which would just have a file name and for blank data frame it would do the same instead of ignoring that dataframe it would add a new row with just file name.

Comment: @PrashantKumar--think it would be easy to fix the issues you Method 2.  We can get it to ignore empty files.  But, first how much faster was it i.e. did it run in a reasonablel time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238029/discussion-between-darrylg-and-prashant-kumar).